# Pandas - Filter Dataframe based on value of variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a variable that has the index value stored. I am trying to filter a Dataframe based on the value stored in this variable.

Given below is how the values are:

```
var = 2  <-- this stores the value for the variable. Now I am trying to create a copy of the Dataframe with only this column.
```

Given below is how my Dataframe is:

```
0,1,2,3,4
apple,4,3,4,5
orange,3,4,5,6
bananas,5,3,5,6
```

Since the variable value is `var = 2`, I am trying to create a new Dataframe that only has the second column. Given below is the expected output:

```
2
3
4
3
```

Comment: Use `usecols=[var])` with `read_csv`

Comment: you have to read only the column for you got a dataframe and take that column only.?

Comment: @coldspeed, I am working with a Dataframe that has been generated after several computations. I am trying to see if I could do this without having to save it and then read again. Could you please assist on this. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that even simpler then? you can use `loc` or something similar, `df.loc[:, [var]]`